# How to validate a AWS ARN using JPA validator

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, javax.validation

How to validate AWS ARN using JPA validator with Hibernate as the provider. Should we use a regex pattern

For example, we would like to make sure that it starts with `arn:aws:iam` for the following role

```
arn:aws:iam::344492858010:role/ABC_role
arn:aws:iam::355433858011:role/DEF_role
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `@Pattern` annotation and write a regex that matches only valid ARNs. Also see https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/beanvalidation/spec/2.0/api/javax/validation/constraints/Pattern.html